# Hex to HunterLab color conversion values

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, hex

I have to convert XYZ to **HunterLab** color. I have tried this below code using this website calculation (http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php). Problem is I didn't get the exact output value.

In this below Fiddle I choose this HEX color code (**"#e33054"**). My HunterLab Result is **43.6862,63.8433,16.6580**

When I compared to this site (http://www.color-hex.com/color/e33054) the output (**43.6863, 63.8431, 16.6536**) value was slightly wrong.

I have attached screenshot from easyrgb.com website. I have used most of the X,Y,Z values from this below image. Which X,Y,Z values I need to use If I want to show the proper exact result.

[image]

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o07mkytb/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function RGBtoXYZ(R, G, B)
{
    var_R = parseFloat( R / 255 )        
    var_G = parseFloat( G / 255 )        
    var_B = parseFloat( B / 255 )        

    if ( var_R > 0.04045 ) var_R = Math.pow(( ( var_R + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ), 2.4)
    else                   var_R = var_R / 12.92
    if ( var_G > 0.04045 ) var_G = Math.pow(( ( var_G + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ), 2.4)
    else                   var_G = var_G / 12.92
    if ( var_B > 0.04045 ) var_B = Math.pow(( ( var_B + 0.055 ) / 1.055 ), 2.4)
    else                   var_B = var_B / 12.92

    var_R = var_R * 100
    var_G = var_G * 100
    var_B = var_B * 100

    //Observer. = 2°, Illuminant = D65
    X = var_R * 0.4124 + var_G * 0.3576 + var_B * 0.1805
    Y = var_R * 0.2126 + var_G * 0.7152 + var_B * 0.0722
    Z = var_R * 0.0193 + var_G * 0.1192 + var_B * 0.9505
    return [X, Y, Z]
}

function XYZtoHunter(X, Y, Z) 
{
    var_Ka = ( 175.0 / 198.04 ) * ( 100.000 + 98.03894 )
    var_Kb = (  70.0 / 218.11 ) * ( 100.000 + 118.1045 )

    Hunter_L = 100.0 * Math.sqrt( Y / 100.000 )
    Hunter_a = var_Ka * ( ( ( X / 98.03894 ) - ( Y / 100.000 ) ) / Math.sqrt( Y / 100.000 ) )
    Hunter_b = var_Kb * ( ( ( Y / 100.000 ) - ( Z / 118.1045 ) ) / Math.sqrt( Y / 100.000 ) )
    return [Hunter_L, Hunter_a, Hunter_b]
}

$("#flat").spectrum({
        color: "#fff",
        showInput: true,
        preferredFormat: "hex6",

        change: function(color) {
      var xyz = color.toRgbString().replace('rgb(','');
            var xyzclr = xyz.replace(')','');
            var mystring = xyzclr;
            var splits = mystring.split(",");
      var bbb = RGBtoXYZ(splits[0], splits[1], splits[2]);
      var ccc = XYZtoHunter(bbb[0], bbb[1], bbb[2]);
      $(".hunterlb").text("Hunter Lab: " + ccc);
      }
      });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely related to precision issues in the computations or in the way the various matrices and illuminants data is rounded.

For reference the CIE XYZ tristimulus values I get using **#e33054** and computed with [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour)
 are as follows:

```
[0.343348156796269 0.190877270586848 0.102641996187028]
```

which is different from the *[34.3357 19.0849 10.2616]* of http://www.color-hex.com/color/e33054

While it is debatable this is a practical issue, you actually have a major implementation problem which is also affecting the website you referenced because you are getting almost the same results:

Your hexadecimal values are assumed to be encoded using sRGB colourspace as per the transfer function and the conversion matrix you use in your `RGBtoXYZ` function. sRGB uses D65 for illuminant which has CIE XYZ tristimulus values as follows:

```
[95.045592705167152 100.000000000000000 108.905775075987847]
```

However your `XYZtoHunter` function uses a different reference whitepoint, close to **C**:

```
[98.03894 100.000 118.1045]
```

This is incorrect, you either need to use the same illuminant than the one used for your sRGB to CIE XYZ conversion, or chromatically adapt your tristimulus values to the one used by the `XYZtoHunter` function.

I have computed the corresponding Hunter Lab values under various illuminants for your test colour:

```
RGB:  [227.000000000000000 48.000000000000000 84.000000000000000]
XYZ:  [0.343348156796269 0.190877270586848 0.102641996187028]
A [46.504499644334125 64.843762706004426 10.523794703973838]
C [43.793566931997233 65.186253736429975 15.569392726793327]
D50 [44.346077037498887 68.520955438240733 13.605094920688586]
D60 [43.868910583037632 67.708490946827283 14.514756461641493]
D65 [43.688755978973106 67.215867228676174 14.862203270379064]
D75 [43.406074307560630 66.195808970976557 15.425166890191013]
F2 [44.802450532649551 68.731031818870903 12.746488963663195]
TL 4 [45.145148163779659 67.238144444096079 12.884252260395227]
UL 3000 [46.368214893847501 65.905510666492106 10.227507087643088]
```

And the code to get those values:

```python
import numpy as np
import colour
from colour.notation.triplet import HEX_to_RGB

RGB = HEX_to_RGB('#e33054')
print('RGB: ', np.round(RGB * 255))
print('XYZ: ', colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(RGB))
for name, illuminant in sorted(
        colour.HUNTERLAB_ILLUMINANTS['cie_2_1931'].items()):
    XYZ = colour.RGB_to_XYZ(
        RGB,
        colour.ILLUMINANTS['cie_2_1931']['D65'],
        colour.XYZ_to_xy(illuminant.XYZ_n),
        colour.sRGB_COLOURSPACE.RGB_to_XYZ_matrix,
        decoding_cctf=colour.sRGB_COLOURSPACE.decoding_cctf)
    print(name, colour.XYZ_to_Hunter_Lab(
        XYZ * 100, XYZ_n=illuminant.XYZ_n, K_ab=illuminant.K_ab))
```